# ConvenienceRobot is a abstract, cannot be instantized?

Tags: android, sphero

This is my code, what should I do?

I already declare

```
import com.orbotix.ConvenienceRobot;
```

on top

What is wrong with my code, I already follow exactly from the SDK example

```
 import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.orbotix.ConvenienceRobot;
import com.orbotix.DualStackDiscoveryAgent;
import com.orbotix.common.DiscoveryException;
import com.orbotix.common.Robot;
import com.orbotix.common.RobotChangedStateListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, RobotChangedStateListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 42;
    private static final float ROBOT_VELOCITY = 0.6f;

    private ConvenienceRobot mRobot;

    private Button front;
    private Button back;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
            Associate a listener for robot state changes with the DualStackDiscoveryAgent.
            DualStackDiscoveryAgent checks for both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth LE.
            DiscoveryAgentClassic checks only for Bluetooth Classic robots.
            DiscoveryAgentLE checks only for Bluetooth LE robots.
       */
    }
    @Override
    public void handleRobotChangedState(Robot robot, RobotChangedStateNotificationType type) {
        switch (type) {
            case Online: {
                //Save the robot as a ConvenienceRobot for additional utility methods
                mRobot = new ConvenienceRobot(robot);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

mRobot = new ConvenienceRobot(robot); is always underline
what wrong?

Comment: Does ConvenienceRobot has a constructor with robot in it?

Comment: now it seem okay after I check the line to     mRobot = new ConvenienceRobot(robot) {
                    @Override
                    public void disconnect() {
                        
                    }
                };